# In POP3, what is the expected first response line to a RETR command?

Tags: pop3

I'm learning about POP3 by reading RFC 1939.

The description of the RETR command says the following:

```
         Possible Responses:
             +OK message follows
             -ERR no such message

         Examples:
             C: RETR 1
             S: +OK 120 octets
             S: <the POP3 server sends the entire message here>
             S: .
```

What does "120 octets" refer to? Is this optional information about the message that may or may not be included, and if so, is "message follows" not required (as specified under "Possible Responses")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "120 octets" refer to? Is this optional information about the message that may or may not be included

Correct, the "120 octets" is optional informational text but is not required text nor can the number of octets be used as definitive for calculating the end of the message data.

> and if so, is "message follows" not required (as specified under "Possible Responses")?

That's why it was stated to be a "possible response" ;-)

Basically, all you can really use from that first line is the first token which will be "+OK" or "-ERR". Everything after that is informational text that may be a helpful when debugging, but not guaranteed to be useful for your code to try and interpret.

I would argue that if it is of the form "# octets", you might be able to use it to show progress as you read data, but that's about the best you can do.

Even so, I would probably recommend using the octet value from the LIST command instead.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was misinterpreting "possible responses" as "the exhaustive list of possible responses" and not "a subset of possible responses". I see later in the spec that it does clarify that only "+OK" and "-ERR" are the required parts of the responses.

Comment: No worries, I can see how you misunderstood that. Your thinking makes perfect sense. I guess I just have the experience with reading RFCs to interpret them the way I did.